# Alinear tres botones horizontalmente en un layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xml

¿Cómo puedo hacer que los botones inferiores se alineen de izquierda a derecha en vez de arriba a abajo y que ocupen todo el ancho del dispositivo que lo ejecute? ¿Puedo emplear porcentajes?

[image: Situación actual]

Adjunto código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="355dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/menuLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noticiasButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Noticias" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/estadoButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Estado" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto(solo es el código relevante para los botones):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/menuLinearLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/midTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:text="Botón 1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/noticiasButton"
        android:text="Botón 2"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/estadoButton"
        android:text="Botón 3"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: diste con la solucion gracias ;D

Comment: !Excelente!... :)

Answer (score 0):

Es por que esos 3 Botones tienen una medida fija que en tu caso es de 100dp :

```
androidlayout_width="100dp"
```

Para que ocuparan todo el ancho solo debes dejarlo igual a como los tienes arriba :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: si pero de esa manera me ocupa un boton todo el ancho. Lo que yo trarto es que en una unica fila tenga los tres botones.

Comment: Y ya intentaste poner android:layout_width="wrap_content" ?

Comment: bien cambie ese atributo y la orientacion del linear layout lo unico que ahora quiero que abarque todo el ancho del layout y se ajusta a la izquierda como podria hacer que se quede de esta manera : https://articles-images.sftcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/08/wechat1.png